# Convergence of the integral definition of the Airy function

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, special-functions, airy-functions

The airy function $\mathrm{Ai}(x)$ can be defined by an improper integral:
$$ \mathrm{Ai}(x) \equiv \frac{1}{\pi} \int^\infty_0\mathrm{d}t \cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+tx\right) \, . $$
I want to prove the convergence of this integral.

---

Wikipedia says this can be proven with the help of [Dirichlet's test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals), which says that
$$ \int fg $$
converges if (1) $f$ is uniformly bounded over all intervals and (2) $g$ is non-negative and monotonically decreasing.

In my attempt, I first make the substitution $u=\frac{t^3}{3}+tx$, so that $\mathrm{d}u = (t^2+x)\mathrm{d}t$. Now we need to write $\mathrm{d}t$ solely in terms of u, which we can expect to be messy but solvable.

Solving for $t$ gives the real solution as
$$ t = \frac{\sqrt[3]{3u+\sqrt{9u^2+4x^3}}}{\sqrt[3]{2}} - \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}x}{\sqrt[3]{3u+\sqrt{9u^2+4x^3}}} \, , $$
and the integral becomes
$$ \mathrm{Ai}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^\infty_0 \mathrm{d}u \cos{u} \left[\left( \frac{\sqrt[3]{3u+\sqrt{9u^2+4x^3}}}{\sqrt[3]{2}} - \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}x}{\sqrt[3]{3u+\sqrt{9u^2+4x^3}}} \right)^2+x\right]^{-1} $$

Now let $\cos{u}$ be $f$ and the other term be $g$, since $\cos{u}$ is obviously bounded, and the other term has a denominator that increase as $u^{2/3}$ and so should be decreasing, we can apply Dirichlet's test and conclude that the integral is convergent.

Is my reasoning correct? And are there more elegant ways of proving this result?

Comment: seems like a lot of work. Just integrate by parts (which is also essentially the idea behind Dirichlet’s test). Multiply and divide the integrand by $t^2+x$. Then, $\int_{R_1}^{R_2}\frac{1}{t^2+x}\cdot \cos(t^3/3+tx)(t^2+x)\,dt=\left[\frac{\sin(t^3/3+tx)}{t^2+x}\right]_{R_1}^{R_2}-\int_{R_1}^{R_2}(-1)\frac{\sin(t^3/3+tx)}{(t^2+x)^2}\cdot 2t\,dt$. The integral now converges absolutely as $R_2\to\infty$ since it decays like $\frac{1}{t^3}$, and the boundary term vanishes at $\infty$.